# Large outbound payload getting stuck in Spring integration Gateway

Tags: spring, httpclient, spring-integration, apache-httpclient-4.x, spring-ws

We have a couple of Spring outbound SOAP WebServices clients (Talking to external WS). We talk to them using Spring Integration Gateway.

**Versions using:**

```
Spring Integration version - 4.0.4.RELEASE
Spring version - 4.1.6.RELEASE
Spring WS - 2.2.4
Apache http client - 4.5.1
```

All works fine when the payload is a few kbs. But when we have a slightly bigger payload (Say 700KB, not huge I know), the processing gets stuck. The thread dump gives the following StackTrace. This happens in both Weblogic(12C) and Apache Tomcat, but only on Linux.

Has somebody encountered this issue before? Is there some configuration inside Spring Integration/Gateway where we can set the writebuffer size?

```
 java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
        at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
        at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:864)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:835)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
        - locked <0x00000000c31b1d00> (a sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:126)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
        at org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity.writeTo(ByteArrayEntity.java:116)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:158)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsConnection.onSendAfterWrite(HttpComponentsConnection.java:121)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:48)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:658)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:606)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
        at org.springframework.integration.ws.MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:81)
        at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:167)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:313)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$1.cloneAndExecute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:92)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice$2.doWithRetry(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:88)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:193)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.doInvoke(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:85)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:69)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.handleRequestMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.doInvokeAdvisedRequestHandler(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:189)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:173)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:255)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$ReplyForwardingMessageChannel.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:263)
```

**UPDATE**
I modified the HttpClient's DefaultSocketConfig (To a custom one) to include setSndBufSize to a large on. Still no effect!

On running `netstat -ant | grep 443` the tcp status is CLOSE_WAIT (And sometimes LAST_ACK)and stays there hanging forever.

Comment: `at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)` looks like the buffers are full - server is not reading or the network is slow - you need to run a network monitor such as wireshark.

Comment: Don't think so, as we have a test application (Using Spring integration/HttpClient/same versions) which sends the same payload without any problem on the same Linux box.

Comment: Well, it's clearly not in spring code `at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)`

Comment: @GaryRussell - Please see update. I modified the HttpClient's DefaultSocketConfig (To a custom one) to include setSndBufSize to a large on. Still no effect!

On running `netstat -ant | grep 443` the tcp status is CLOSE_WAIT (And sometimes LAST_ACK)and stays there hanging forever.

Comment: As I said, you need to look at a network trace - the problem is downstream of spring and apache-http.

Comment: @GaryRussell - Thanks. Did a lot of tcpdump/wireshark and turns out to be a N/W issue. We have a temporary workaround by routing the requests via proxy and it works. Thanks very much for your help. If you put one of your relevant comments as answer, I am more than happy to up-vote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)

It looks to me like the buffers are full - server is not reading fast enough or the network is slow - you need to run a network monitor such as wireshark